# MYSQL Error : Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, vert.x

I am trying to connect to mysql from my vertx application. I am getting below error :

io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLException: Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)   at io.vertx.mysqlclient.impl.codec.CommandCodec.handleErrorPacketPayload(CommandCodec.java:116)     at io.vertx.mysqlclient.impl.codec.InitCommandCodec.decodeInit1(InitCommandCodec.java:177)  at io.ve

The code is as below :

```
    MySQLConnectOptions connectOptions = new MySQLConnectOptions()
            .setPort(3306)
            .setHost("localhost")
            .setDatabase("bookstore")
            .setUser("user1")
            .setPassword("pass123");

    // Pool options
    PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions()
            .setMaxSize(5);

    // Create the client pool
    MySQLPool client = MySQLPool.pool(Vertx.vertx(),connectOptions, poolOptions);

    // A simple query
    client.query("SELECT * FROM country WHERE name='julien'",ar->
        {
            if(ar.succeeded())
            {
                RowSet result = ar.result();
                System.out.println("Got " + result.size() + " rows ");
            } else {
                ar.cause().printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failure: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
            }
            // Now close the pool
                client.close();
            });
}
```

Although I am able to connect to my sql server in workbench using same credentials.
Could someone please help in understanding the issue.

Comment: Either you're sending the wrong password, or `user1@localhost` hasn't been granted permission to the `bookstore` database.

Comment: I have granted all privileges to user1. Still its not working. Is there anyway by which I can print in logs what is exactly the issue?

Comment: @Barmar  These are the grants for the user1 :GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bookstore`.* TO `user1`@`localhost`
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `user1`@`localhost`

Comment: Having a view of the entire class where there is the error could assist in better debugging. 
- Make sure the Vertx instance you are passing in `MySQLPool.pool` is the Vertx instance of the used in the class. You could try `MySQLPool.pool(getVertx()..`
-Other few trials would be to `.setHost()` with the IP address (instead of localhost)

Comment: Same issue for me with vertx 4.1 and mysql 8. All options are set correctly still I get Access denied error. My Spring Boot app with plain jdbc driver is able to connect to db with all the same settings. I even set setSSLMode to false but still getting this issue